# Algolia type conflicts with react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, algolia, npm-build

Im making an app that uses Instantsearch-react-hooks. On the development server everything runs fine. But when i try to build the project bellow errors occure:

```
node_modules/@algolia/ui-components-highlight-vdom/dist/esm/Highlight.d.ts:10:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'span' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>', but here has type 'IntrinsicElement'.
10             span: IntrinsicElement;
              ~~~~
 node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3201:13
   3201             span: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>;  
                    ~~~~
   'span' was also declared here.
node_modules/@algolia/ui-components-highlight-vdom/dist/esm/Highlight.d.ts:11:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'mark' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'IntrinsicElement'.
11             mark: IntrinsicElement;
              ~~~~
 node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3171:13
   3171             mark: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>;
                    ~~~~
   'mark' was also declared here.
node_modules/@algolia/ui-components-shared/dist/esm/Renderer.d.ts:8:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'children' must be of type '{}', but here has type 'ComponentChildren'.
8             children: ComponentChildren;
             ~~~~~~~~
 node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3093:46
   3093         interface ElementChildrenAttribute { children: {}; }
                                                     ~~~~~~~~
   'children' was also declared here.
node_modules/react-router/dist/lib/polyfills/start-transition.d.ts:2:38 - error TS2339: Property 'startTransition' does not exist on type 'typeof React'.
2 declare const _default: typeof React.startTransition;
```

From this i understand that the types of span and mark are conflicting with those provided by react library.

For the steps i've taken. I updated the npm as well as node, but it didn't help. i also made

> npm update

which did nothing as well. Tried updating react to the latest version but still nothing. I could probably change some code in the nodemodules but i want everything to work fine on every instalation becouse im using a netlify server which runs

> npm run build

on every commit i make.